# How to know if a machine is an Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to know from a command line shell if I am currently on a Google Compute Engine machine or somewhere else (development machine)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per the [metadata docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#runninggce):

> You can easily detect if your applications or scripts are running within a Compute Engine instance by using the metadata server. When you make a request to the server, any response from the metadata server will contain the `Metadata-Flavor: Google` header. You can look for this header to reliably detect if you are running in Compute Engine.
>
> For example, the following curl request returns a `Metadata-Flavor: Google` header, indicating that the request is being made from within a Compute Engine instance.
>
> ```
> me@my-inst:~$ curl metadata.google.internal -i
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Metadata-Flavor: Google
> Content-Type: application/text
> Date: Thu, 10 Apr 2014 19:24:27 GMT
> Server: Metadata Server for VM
> Content-Length: 22
> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>
> 0.1/
> computeMetadata/
> ```

Answer (score 11):

Here is python implementation via [socket.getaddrinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo)

```py
import socket


def is_gce_instance():
  """Check if it's GCE instance via DNS lookup to metadata server.
  """
  try:
    socket.getaddrinfo('metadata.google.internal', 80)
  except socket.gaierror:
    return False
  return True
```

Comment: While this solution works, the downside is that you cannot pass a custom timeout to `getaddrinfo`, therefore it will hand for about 5 seconds before raising an exception when not running in  GAE instance

Answer (score 8):

You can also [use the `dmidecode` utility to probe the virtual hardware](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/#dmi) if you don't want to make a network call:

```
my@myinst:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-vendor | grep Google
Google
```

Comment: This avoids the network call and is therefore more reliable and fast. Additionally, the `dmidecode` method works for other cloud providers like Digital Ocean, for example.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do a DNS lookup for the Metadata server, instead of actually calling it.

For example, doing `dig +short metadata.google.internal` *inside* a Google Compute instance would output something like this:

```
[root@vm-1]# dig +short metadata.google.internal
169.254.169.254
```

If, however, you do the same command (`dig +short metadata.google.internal`) inside a standard server, outside of Google Cloud, you could get an empty response.

So to check, all you need to do (in `bash` for instance) is:

```
GMETADATA_ADDR=`dig +short metadata.google.internal`
if [[ "${GMETADATA_ADDR}" == "" ]]; then
    echo "I am NOT in a Google VM!"
else
    echo "I AM INSIDE a Google VM! Whoohoo!"
fi
```