# Node.js check if running locally or in google cloud VM?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

In a Node.js script, How can I check if I'm running in Google Cloud VM or locally?

I'm not using Google App Engine.

Is it possible to do this without making any network requests, synchronously?

Comment: This might also be of value ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911775/how-to-know-if-a-machine-is-an-google-compute-engine-instance

Comment: The correct method as mention by Kolban is to check the instance metadata. Environment variables are not reliable.

Comment: Thanks @Kolban! That's what I was looking for (although would be better to not have to make a network request).

Answer (score 3):

You could, for example, check for the [various environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#environment_variables) that will be set, such as `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` or `GAE_INSTANCE`, accessible from a Node.js script as:

```js
process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT
```

Comment: is this the offial way?

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/environment` on the VM, append the following:

```
GCLOUD=1
```

And then in Node:

```
const isRunningInVM = Boolean(process.env.GCLOUD)
```