# Detect Cloud Type in VM

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud

In a solution, we are planning multiple clouds (AWS, Azure and GCP) as a solution. Same code will be deployed in multiple VMs running in different clouds.

In many cases, we need to detect cloud and write the code accordingly. e.g. Use AWS S3 SDK when running on AWS and Azure Blob SDK when running on Azure.

In AWS, we can hit metadata URL to detect (`http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/`) if it is AWS.

I am wondering if there is any way to detect the cloud provider inside the VM (like through environment variables or metadata URL or any other way).

Preferred code can be in `python` or a shell script.

Comment: A simple search using "azure vm meta data" lead me to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/instance-metadata-service?tabs=linux

Comment: For google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911775/how-to-know-if-a-machine-is-an-google-compute-engine-instance

Comment: Which language? Which clouds? I wrote a library that does this. The answer @erik-oppedijk is close but there are several factors to consider. There are three methods: 1) cloud-init files. 2) System device files. 3) Metadata. Metadata can be disabled and should be the last item checked if the other two fail or are not available. For most cloud vendors, this file has the information you want. Look for **cloud-name**: /run/cloud-init/instance-data.json

Comment: @JohnHanley shell script, python and java.

Comment: Edit your question with those details. However, limit your question to one language and the set of clouds. The code that I wrote is in .NET and is too large to post as an answer. The process is simple to understand, the implementation takes a fair amount of code. Probably too complex for a shell script, but a shell script could call a program or Python script.

Answer (score 3):

With the answers of CSharpRocks and Dany L combined:

**Azure:**

http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2021-02-01

**Google**

http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1
With header: `Metadata-Flavor: Google`

URL resolves to: http://169.254.169.254/

**Amazon**

http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

**documentation**:

- Don't use a proxy server for these request
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/instance-metadata-service?tabs=windows
- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Answer (score 3):

**We may consider multiple ways to identify current Cloud relying to the instance metadata**

1. Cloud-init
2. Metadata base URL
3. Metadata specific item
4. Custom Tag/Metadata

**Cloud-init**

```bash
#! /bin/bash

# cloud-name, cloud_name, cloud_id, platform
cloud=$(cloud-init query cloud-name)

case ${cloud} in
  aws)   echo "AWS Cloud"     ;;
  azure) echo "Azure Cloud"   ;;
  gce)   echo "GCP Cloud"     ;;
  *)     echo "Unknown Cloud" ;;
esac
```

**Metadata base URL**

```bash
#! /bin/bash

# set -x -e

# AWS Cloud
token=$(curl -X PUT -s -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600" http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token)
status=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: ${token}" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/)
[[ "${status}" -eq 200 ]] && cloud="aws"

# Azure Cloud
status=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -H "Metadata: true" --noproxy "*" "http://169.254.169.254/metadata?api-version=2021-02-01&format=text")
[[ "${status}" -eq 200 ]] && cloud="azure"

# GCP Cloud
status=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/ || true)
[[ "${status}" -eq 200 ]] && cloud="gcp"

echo $cloud
```

**Custom Tag/Metadata**

For this example, we should set Tag `Cloud=aws` on AWS, `Cloud=azure` on Azure and Metadata `Cloud=gcp` for GCP at instances creation.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

# set -x -e

# AWS Cloud
token=$(curl -X PUT -s -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600" http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token)
get_cloud=$(curl -s -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: ${token}" http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance/Cloud)
[[ "${get_cloud}" == "aws" ]] && cloud="aws"

# Azure Cloud
get_cloud=$(curl -s -H "Metadata: true" --noproxy "*" "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/compute/tags?api-version=2021-02-01&format=text" | awk -F ';|Cloud:' '/Cloud/ {print $2}')
[[ "${get_cloud}" == "azure" ]] && cloud="azure"

# GCP Cloud
get_cloud=$(curl -s -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/Cloud || true)
[[ "${get_cloud}" == "gcp" ]] && cloud="gcp"

echo $cloud
```

**Additional information**

1. [AWS - Instance metadata and user data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)
2. [Azure Instance Metadata Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/instance-metadata-service?tabs=linux)
3. [GCP - Access VM metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/querying-metadata)
4. [Cloud-init - Instance metadata](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/explanation/instancedata.html#instance-metadata)